# Why is less than 9, counting the 9?

Tags: java, arrays

The java book I have has various questions and one of them I was doing had listed in the back of the book the correct answer, as I have written below. I understand how everything works. Like why you don't want to use >=, how it outputs when something is out of order, ect. I just don't understand why the for line requires it do be <9 as opposed to <=9 or <10. I know the very last number doesn't have to loop because the one before it gets compared, but if it's less than 9 wouldn't it stop before the 9th element, making it so the 10th element doesn't ever get compared?

Error Code:

```
double[] scores = {2.5, 3.9, 4.8, 6.2, 6.2, 7.4, 7.9, 8.5, 8.5, 9.9};
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
      if (scores[i] >= scores[i+1])
        System.out.println(i + " and "  + (i + 1)
        + " elements of score are out of order.");
```

Correct Code:

```
double[] scores = {2.5, 3.9, 4.8, 6.2, 6.2, 7.4, 7.9, 8.5, 8.5, 9.9};
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
        if (scores[i] > scores[i+1])
          System.out.println(i + " and "  + (i + 1)
          + " elements of score are out of order.");
```

Edit: The question is:
The following is suppose to ensure the elements of scores is in non-decreasing order. However, there are errors in the code. Find and correct the errors.

Comment: The 'correct code' portion looks wrong to me.  The loop start at index 1, so the 0th index never gets compared.  <9 stops at the 8th index, which is the 9th element.

Comment: You need to count from 0 to scors.length-2 (because length-1 is the last element, and you want to make sure you compare the second last to the last). Optional you can count from 1..scores.length-1 and compare i-1 with i.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that indexes start at `0`. There are 10 elements in the list. That means the indexes range from `0-9`.

You are accessing the `i` and the `i+1` element. So in the `for` loop when `i` is `8`, you are looking at the items at index `8` and `9`. If you let the loop go up to `9`, then you will try to access the elements at index `9` and `10` and get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: So the book is wrong. considering the index is start off at 1?

Comment: Possibly. Hard to say without the book in front of me, let alone the question.

Comment: The book is right in regards to 'i < 9' however element 0 and element 1 never get compared to each other. Provided there is another way of ensuring element 0 is the smallest element, the code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count `i` from 0 to `scores.length-2` (because `length-1` is the last element, and you want to make sure you compare the second last to the last).

Alternatively you can count from 1..scores.length-1 and compare index `i-1` with `i`:

```
double[] scores = {2.5, 3.9, 4.8, 6.2, 6.2, 7.4, 7.9, 8.5, 8.5, 9.9};
for (int i = 0; i <= scores.length - 2; i++)
    if (scores[i] >= scores[i+1])
        throw new RuntimeException(i + " and "  + (i + 1) + " not strictly monotonic");

double[] scores = {2.5, 3.9, 4.8, 6.2, 6.2, 7.4, 7.9, 8.5, 8.5, 9.9};
for (int i = 1; i <= scores.length - 1; i++)
    if (scores[i-1] >= scores[i])
        throw new RuntimeException((i-1) + " and "  + i  + " not strictly monotonic");
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand what you're trying to do. You should start looping from the 0th index up to <= 9 or <10. Always remember that array index starts from 0

Comment: I'm not doing anything, this is from the book. Copied and pasted here.

Comment: Well then, there must be something wrong in the book